# Redirect for locations that don't exist but only in the root directory

Tags: .htaccess

For my website I want all requests that go to the root (that aren't an already existing file) to go to redirect.php but I don't want it to redirect to that file if the request is in a sub-directory but instead have those go to generic error pages.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This is my full .htaccess file

```
# Disabling directory listing
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 

# Redirecting any traffic that doesn't exist to the index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it all you need to add is a condition to prevent your rule getting applied when a "sub directory" is requested:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+/.+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or you implement a rule that only matches paths that do *not* target "sub directories":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+$ /redirect.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```